# Why some errors are hidden from unwrap in golang's net/http/transport

Tags: http, go

I do retry HTTP requests on some errors. One is `syscall.EPIPE`. I do check with `errors.Is(err, syscall.EPIPE)`. But in very very rare cases I see in a log the `broken pipe` error that is not retried:

```
level=error msg="can't call 'http://<...>': Post \"http://<...>\": net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: write tcp 172.18.0.25:44664->172.18.0.11:8000: write: broken pipe"
```

It looks like in these cases the error is returned from *net/http/transpot.go*:

```golang
return fmt.Errorf("net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: %v", err)
```

Just wonder why the `%v` is preferred there over `%w`?

Comment: Looks like none of the errors are wrapped in this file, which makes me think it's by choice and not an oversight. Still worth opening an issue, I'd say (unless there is one already; haven't checked).